# Abstract definition of inner product: Where does the conjugate symmetry requirement come from and what conjugate property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, inner-products

In various texts and articles I've read which take aim to define properties in their most abstract and general terms, without reference to any particular sets or fields, the inner product is defined on a vector space with three conditions: left-linearity, positive definiteness, and conjugate symmetry.

When I in turn seek to define the property of conjugacy in the same abstract sense, these same sources tell me that it isn't a rigorously defined property in mathematics, and that it depends on a context and special applications, wherein conjugacy is defined. Often times in reference to inner products, conjugates are defined in the very familiar complex number space most of us would think of... the conjugate self-symmetric reals or the complex numbers are used in practice, but we need not define a conjugate in this typical way, nor are we required to define conjugates on real or complex numbers at all but on general elements of some other space. Im fine with this, I suppose.

But I come back to the definition of inner product, and am left wondering what kind of conjugate is being referred to. Does it matter?  Do the authors of these articles have it in their head on some level they're talking about complex numbers? Maybe any definition of conjugacy can be used and it really doesnt matter. But why is the condition in the definition at all?

> What is so special about an otherwise undefinable operation (i.e. conjugacy) that makes it a required condition for another definable operation (i.e. inner product)?

Comment: A generalization of complex conjugation is not "undefinable." Simply put, it's a (nontrivial) involution of the (possibly skew) field, i.e. a(n anti-)automorphism of order two. The reason it's used in the definition of a general inner product (i.e. a sesquilinear form) is because this generalizes the complex inner product in many important ways (although we can and do define symmetric bilinear forms that are not sesquilinear and talk about them, too). The reason it's used in the definition of the complex inner product is because then the norm matches the norm as a real inner product space.

Comment: @runway44 To be fair to whatever source SquishyRhode looked at, "conjugation" is indeed overloaded in mathematics, and its usage depends on context. In (semi)group theory, conjugating $a$ by $b$ means considering $b^{-1}ab$. I'm sure the word has taken other meanings in other contexts. But, in the context of inner products, the conjugate is typically taken to be the complex conjugate.

Comment: @runway I didnt specify that complex conjugation was undefinable. Youre straw-manning me.  I said that conjugation was undefinable, and I used complex conjugation as one particular example that is usually implied.  The problem I have with conjugate symmetry being used in the inner product definition is that it seems to imply complex numbers are at play, when the definition being used is meant to be absolutely abstract.  Furthermore, I have (had) yet to see a legitimate mathematical reason why conjugate symmetry ought to be required in the definition at all. The application is so niche.

Comment: @TheoBendit Indeed. So can group conjugation also be applied to the inner product definition?  If inner products definition is written with complex numbers in mind then surely the definition is not abstract enough?  You dont have to go far to find "whatever source Im using". You could literally google search, read wikipedia, or crack open any abstract book on the subject... if you pay attention and try hard to generalize everything, the complication I bring up will become apparent.

Comment: I didn't say you "specified that complex conjugation was undefinable," I said "a generalization of complex conjugation is not "undefinable,"" which is the best reading I can get out of "[unnamed, unquoted] sources tell me it ["the property of conjugacy"] isn't a rigorously defined property in mathematics [...]" The term "strawman" is for arguments and debates, not conversations and discussions with good faith interpretations, even if erroneous. Group theory conjugation is not relevant. A "legitimate mathematical reason why conjugate symmetry out to be required in the definition at all" is that

Comment: it is one way to generalize the situation for complex numbers, though it's not the only way - besides sesquilinear forms there are also plain old symmetric bilinear forms, so it's not "required" as part of a definition of *a* form, just part of the definition of a *sesquilinear* form specifically. Both bilinear and sesquilinear forms (and another - symplectic) are useful for defining classical groups which lead to classifying simple finite groups and simple Lie groups / algebras. It's not surprising that sesquilinear forms are usually tied to the complex numbers, though - for practical

Comment: purposes that's where the topology, algebraic closedness, & characteristic zero all come into play, other fields are not as well-known to students, and it's where geometry and tons of physics are relevant. Since your claims about what your sources are saying seem to contradict my own experience with reading sources on these subjects, I am baffled by how you're talking about them as if they back you up here. Googling "inner products why conjugate" brings all sorts of answers. What "complication" are you mysteriously alluding to in your last comment? Opaqueness and confrontation are not helping.

Comment: @SquishyRhode Ah, no, I didn't mean to suggest that! I'm just saying that the word "conjugate" and all its various forms (I believe the linguistic term is "conjugations") have other meanings in mathematics. In the most common inner product space theory I'm used to, the word "conjugate" refers exclusively to complex conjugate (not at all to the group theory sense). Although, I dimly remember stumbling across some slightly less standard inner product theory that worked with a more abstract conjugate on a more abstract field (in the sense that runway44 was talking about).